# Dataframe Editing

Tags: python, pandas

So I have this data frame called games which looks like so:

```
Year | Publisher | Games_Sold

2001 | Comp_A    | 14.0

2001 | Comp_B    | 3.4

2002 | Comp_A    | 4.4

2002 | Comp_B    | 9.9
```

This data frame was created by typing

```
games.groupby(['Year', 'Publisher'], as_index=False).agg({'Games_Sold':'sum'})
```

Now what I want to do is create a simplified dataframe that outputs the Publisher that sold the most games in a given year. It would look like this:

```
Year | Publisher | Games_Sold

2001 | Comp_A    | 14.0

2002 | Comp_B    | 9.9
```

There has to be a way to do this but I've been running into multiple walls and errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This does not make sense, you ask for "most sold given a year", but your expected output sums the `Games_Sold` over the years. For example Comp_A is 2001 + 2002 games sold

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I made a mistake, didn't mean to add them. Will correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is `GroupBy.transform`. Difference between regular `GroupBy.sum` and `transform` is that the latter will give you an vector/array back with the same length as your dataframe. While `GroupBy.sum` will give you an aggregated dataframe back.

This way you can compare these values to your original dataframe:

```
df = df[df['Games_Sold'] == df.groupby('Year')['Games_Sold'].transform('max')]
```

```
   Year Publisher  Games_Sold
0  2001    Comp_A       14.00
3  2002    Comp_B        9.90
```

**Details**

`GroupBy.transform` give us:

```
df.groupby('Year')['Games_Sold'].transform('max')

0   14.00
1   14.00
2    9.90
3    9.90
Name: Games_Sold, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can group it again, but this time use max

```
games.groupby(['Year', 'Publisher'], as_index=False)['Games Sold'].max())
```

Comment: I've tried this method before and it has not worked. It simply returns the same data frame that was originally created at the top of my post.

Comment: that would be impossible. a group by on the year and publisher won't show comp_A and comp_B on the same year